# how to only allow one domain to access

Tags: .htaccess

I have one domain (http:// xxxxxxxx.net) with hosting running wordpress , and one cloud server for storeing file
I got direct file url from cloud server, (http:// xxxxxxx.com/uplaod/123/123.mp4)
How can I make it the file url only can play on my domain (http:// xxxxxxxx.net) for video playing.

I try this htaccess

```
# ALLOW USER BY IP
<Limit GET POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from xxxxxxxxx.net
</Limit>
```

When i visit this url 
http:// xxxxxxx.com/uplaod/123/123.mp4  
got 403 forbidden,

My wordpress post video link i put 
http:// xxxxxxx.com/uplaod/123/123.mp4
Video can't play.

Sorry for my bad English, hope you all can understand what I am asking.
Thanks

Comment: `allow from` only works with ip-addresses. Hostnames are not automatically resolved to an ip. If `xxxxx.net` is localhost, you can whitelist 127.0.0.1. Otherwise I think you can ping the server to find out it's ip, then add that one to the whitelisted ip's.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this to your `upload` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://xxxxxxxx.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

This checks that a request is being **referred to** by the "xxxxxxxx.net" site, and to allow that referral, but not referrals from other sites or by simply typing the URL in the browser's address bar. Keep in mind that this is *no guarantee* to prevent direct access, as the referer field can be forged.

Comment: tried to added to upload folder with the one you provide,
xxxxx.net video player can't play video after added and direct url also can't visit

Comment: @user2999240  you remove all the "deny from all" stuff you had before?